# triangle type function with only 2 angles given

Tags: c, function

Implement a function that is given 2 positive integers representing 2 angles of a triangle. If the triangle is right, isosceles, or both, the function should return 1, 2 or 3, respectively. Otherwise it should return 0.

im actually just started learning C language and cant move on cause i cant find an answer to this problem.
would like a reference to see where are my mistakes.

dont need to print it, only the function.
without using loops only if statements.

```
int TriangleType (unsigned num1, unsigned num2){
    int result;
    if(num1 == 90 || num2 == 90 || num1 + num2 == 90){
        result = 1;
    } else if(num1 == num2 || 180 - (num1+num2) == num1 || 180 - (num1+num2) == num2) {
        result = 2;
    } else if((num1 == 90 || num2 == 90 || num1 + num2 == 90) && (num1 == num2 || 180 - (num1+num2) == num1 || 180 - (num1+num2) == num2)){
        result = 3;
    } else if (num1 + num2 >= 180){
        result = -1;
    } else {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

thats the start so u can see what is the direction...
maybe got mistakes even here at the start =)

Comment: I think the problem is the fact that im using only 2 angles.

Comment: It's a little unclear whether your problem is how to code or your understanding of triangles.  What happens when you run the code?

Comment: look thats my code right now i edited the post, now it passes all numbers but when it gets 90 & 45 it fails

Comment: You are on the right track, but with 90 and 45 it's hitting the first `if` statement and then going to the end of the function (skipping over the `else` statements).  I suggest to define variables `int num3 = 180 - num1 - num2`, `int right = 0`, `int isosceles = 0`.  Then have one `if` statement to check for a right angle (set `right = 1` if right), and a completely separate `if` statement to check for isosceles (set `isosceles = 1` if isosceles).  Then another completely separate `if` statement to set the return value based on the values of `right` and `isosceles`.

Comment: Dont get what i did wrong. Cause if it hits the first if when the angle is 90 then i should get 1 as a result, whats wrong with it?

Comment: The first `if` statement condition is true (one of the angles is 90), so `result` is set to `1`.  The `else` statements don't run, because `else` statements are only run if the `if` statement condition is false.  When you have 45 and 90 it is both right and isosceles, but it will never set `result=3` because the `else` doesn't run.

Comment: Ok tony i got you, so how can i rewrite my own code to get this problem fixed? Without changing what u suggested, can u do it for me so i can understand?

Comment: I feel your frustration but I think it's discouraged to provide full code in response to this type of question (someone else more experienced will no doubt jump in if I am wrong).  My earlier comment about using intermediate variables and separate `if` statements suggests a solution.

Comment: I understand, but my english isnt perfect and i never used this kind of intermediate variables so i dont really know how to actually implement those.. thats why im asking from u to change my own code to get the problem fixed so i can really understand and learn from it.

Comment: I agree with @Tony on providing full code would be just doing the work on behalf of OP, but, I feel its easier to convey in code than in English due to OP's challenges in understanding the English language

Answer (score 1):

```
int TriangleType (unsigned num1, unsigned num2)
{
    //Calculate the third angle and keep in num3
        unsigned num3 = 180 - (num1 + num2); 
    
    //We declare a variable "result" and initialize it with 0
    //This way if none of our if conditions match, we would simply return 0 by "return result;".        
    unsigned int result = 0; 

        if (num1 == 90 || num2 == 90 || num3 == 90) //if any of our angles are 90-degree
                result += 1; //Add 1 to result (which is 0 at this point)
        if ((num1==num2) || (num2 == num3) || (num1 == num3)) //if any two angles are same i.e. isosceles
                result += 2; //Add 2 to result (which is 1 if previous if condition was true otherwise its 0) )
    
    /*
    At this point :
     1) If it was neither right-angled or isoscles 
        both the if statements will be false and result will remain 0

     2) If it was right-angled we did "result += 1" i.e. "result = result + 1"
        So, In case first "if" condition is true, result is 1 otherwise its 0

     3) If it was isoscles we did "result += 2" i.e. "result = result + 2"
        So, second "if" condition is true, result becomes result + 2 ie 
        if result was 0 it becomes 2 or if it was 1 it becomes 3.
    */


        return result;
}
```

Comment: There will not be returned -1 for the +180 angle, but I really like the solution.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: Added comments to explain the code as per @EricPostpischil suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Correct logic is:

```
int TriangleType(unsigned num1, unsigned num2)
{
  int result;
  if (num1 == 90 || num2 == 90 || num1 + num2 == 90) {
    if (num1 == num2 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num1 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num2)
      result = 3;
    else
      result = 1;
  } else if (num1 == num2 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num1 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num2) {
    result = 2;
  } else if (num1 + num2 >= 180) {
    result = -1;
  } else {
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

In your program there is a mistake in logic in the first if statement. You are asking whether the triangle is right and if so you evaluate is as one. But in reality it can be right and isosceles at the same time, but it's checked just in third if statement to which you won't get since you return one. So you have to check the condition in that first statement.

```
if (num1 == 90 || num2 == 90 || num1 + num2 == 90) {
    if (num1 == num2 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num1 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num2)
      result = 3;
    else
      result = 1;
  }
```

Then it should work correctly.

Good practice for the future is use function for any for loop, condition, etc. so you do not need to copy you code. It is much more efficient to write just one function, more readable for the other programmers and if there is a mistake, you will need to fix it at just one place and not multiple ones.

I would write it as:

```
int is_isosceles(unsigned num1, unsigned num2)
{
  if (num1 == num2 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num1 || 180 - (num1 + num2) == num2)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int TriangleType(unsigned num1, unsigned num2)
{
  int result;
  if (num1 == 90 || num2 == 90 || num1 + num2 == 90) {
    if (is_isosceles(num1, num2))
      result = 3;
    else
      result = 1;
  } else if (is_isosceles(num1, num2)) {
    result = 2;
  } else if (num1 + num2 >= 180) {
    result = -1;
  } else {
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Condition functions can be of type **bool**, but include library:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and sketch a solution without giving you the complete code...

```
int TriangleType (unsigned num1, unsigned num2){

    int right = 0;
    int isosceles = 0;
    int result = 0;

    if( /* conditions for right angle */ ){
        right = 1;
    } 

    if( /* conditions for isosceles */ ) {
        isosceles = 1;
    } 

    if ( right == 1 && isosceles == 1 ) {
        result = 3;
    } else if ( right == 1) {
        result = 1;
    } else if ( isosceles == 1 ) { 
        /* ... */
    } /*...*/
    return result;
}
```

It could be made shorter but since you are just starting out this is probably best.